# predict_proba() giving probabilities as 0s and 1s but few intermediate values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am working on a breast cancer detection classification problem. I have downloaded the dataset from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/yasserh/breast-cancer-dataset

I want to predict:

a) Whether the tumour is Benign or Malignant
and

b) What is the probability(0-1) that a tumour is malignant.

I am implementing a Random Forest Classifier.

The issue I am facing is that when I use the `rf_classifier.predict_proba()` method, the probabilities that I obtain contain a lot of 1s and 0s but few intermediate values. Ideally, I was expecting all values to be decimals between 0 and 1 in the Probability column.

Is this method the correct approach for achieving the objective? If yes, how to solve the issue?

The classifier performs very well.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
scaler = StandardScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
rf_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = rf_classifier.predict(X_test)

y_pred_proba = rf_classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

results = np.column_stack((y_test[:200], y_pred[:200], y_pred_proba[:200]))
np.set_printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True)
print("Actual | Predicted | Probability")
print(results)
```

Output:

[image: output]

Classification report:

[image: Classification report]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am afraid this is not a *programming* question, hence it is actually off-topic here; please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: @desertnaut With all due respect, kindly explain how I am supposed to know this is not a "programming" question without already knowing the answer. Even then, it seems it would be off-topic on other sites.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, or why the fact that you "ideally" would expect *all* values to be decimals is a programming question. It is true that someone could answer "remove the `precision=2` part to get the full precision" (I am not even sure what `suppress` does) and consider this to be on-topic; not me though, and that's why we have a system where multiple users need to vote for a question to be closed. As for the other sites, an ML theory/methodology answer could explain why there should not be such "ideal" expectations.

Comment: The question I am asking is why `predict_proba()` outputs 1s and 0s. That _seems_ like a programming/implementation question. I expect _most_ of the values to be floats between 0 and 1 because by my knowledge probabilities predicted using continuous features _should_ lie _between_ 0 and 1. Btw `suppress` is used to print in standard notation rather than scientific notation.

Comment: But they *do* lie between 1 and 0, don't they? It's only ~half of them that *seem* to be exactly 0 or 1 - did you try to change `precision`, as advised?

Comment: Please also notice that implementation questions are expected to include a [mre], which is also not the case here.

Comment: Especially since you do see highly-confident predictions elsewhere (0.98, 0.01), I second desertnaut's suggestion.

Comment: I tried changing `precision`, didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is between 0 and 1 only when the samples in a leaf contain 0 and 1. For example, when a leaf contains nine benign and one malignant sample, the probability of being malignant is 10 percent and vice. versa.

Now, when you traverse through the random forest and reach a leaf with impure samples (containing both benign and malignant samples), the output will be in decimals.

However, in your model, most leaves are pure that results in 0 and 1 predictins.

Comment: Or it is just the `precision=2` print requirement that gives this impression...

Comment: Note that the leaf that a sample finds itself in would have to be pure in _every tree_ of the random forest for this to happen.  That's possible, for easily classified observations, but it's a higher bar than for a single (esp. fully-grown) tree.

Comment: ... let alone a *forest* @BenReiniger